# JQuery innerHTML after changePage not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, innerhtml

I'm using jQuery mobile (For a Cordova app), and I want to change to a different page in the solution and after that, change the content of a div within that new page:

```
        $.mobile.changePage("otherPage.html");
        $("#div_in_otherPage").html("Hello");
```

But it doesn't work. It moves to the new page but the DIV doesn't change. I tried not changing to the new page and putting a DIV with the same ID in the previous page, and it does change the content of that DIV. What makes me think that the $.html is attached to the DOM of the previous page.
Also tried using plain javascript with innerHTML instead $.html, but same result.

Do I have to do something else after the changePage? Or should I use another method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't load the page automatically so I had to put the innerHTML inside an event when the page is ready:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#otherPage", function(event,data){
    $("#div_in_otherPage").html("Hello");
});
```